# Проверка и запуск приложений

Tags: android

Как реализовать что бы при нажатии на button приложение проверяла установлено ли другое приложение и если оно есть то запустить его. Иначе открыть страницу, к примеру google play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверку на наличие приложения можно осуществить [следующим образом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28175210):

```
public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        return true;
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Для запуска приложения можно воспользоваться методом [`getLaunchIntentForPackage (String packageName)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29).

А открыть приложение в Google Play [можно так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11753070):

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```